Parsing sol transaction data in golang
I'm trying to write a simple go program to parse Solana transactions (swaps mostly) to establish a framework to collect ohlc data, based on sol transactions.
( I have done this for several other block chains,but having a real hard time doing this for Solana, due to lack of familiarity)
Could some point me in the right direction of some go with some examples how to accomplish this?
Right now I'm using RPC calls to get the slot, associated block and transactions. But I'm a bit stuck.with decoding these.
As an example, I would love to parse this transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/4MxyeXUQfEAKH7z8X9fNomNAF1CcQ87LH47zqj3EbwaLMwiM5ABA8WKgtADN3Pu2VS354Rsbe5LTEe43QawXJE1d
and extract this information:
Swap
0.048
image
WSOL
for
0.048204732
image
WSOL
on
Jupiter Aggregator v6
Thank you!

Ok looks like I good a rough solution working. It's not final, but enough to get other people started
Assuming you are using anchor-go

download your IDL file, in this case we assume jupiter.idl
install anchor-go using: go install github.com/gagliardetto/anchor-go
generate the bindings: anchor-go --remove-account-suffix --src jupiter.json
sadly right now you need to fix some minor compile errors. Mostly it complains about missing structs, which can be solved, by removing 'Swap' in front of the generated types.go files
utilize the following code fragment as a starting point

    utx, err := client.GetTransaction(context.TODO(), sig, &rpc.GetTransactionOpts{
        MaxSupportedTransactionVersion: &txVersion,
    })

    tx, err := utx.Transaction.GetTransaction()

    meta, err := tx.AccountMetaList()

    for _, instruction := range tx.Message.Instructions {
        parsedInstruction, err2 := jupiter.DecodeInstruction(meta, instruction.Data)

        print("instructions %v, %s ", parsedInstruction, err2)
    }


This will now provide you with the swapped data, where for a given transaction we are able to decode the content. If it fails, an error is generated and we move on.
This will only give you the partial instructions. I update this, when I find the complete answer in a couple of days.
If you debug the transaction object, it could look something like this:

